# Error en nodejs

Tags: nodejs, express-session

Estoy tratando de hacer lo siguiente.
Tengo lo sgts endpoints.

```
/
/secret
/user/login  //Post-Get
/user/logout //Post
/user/register //Post-Get
/user/recuperar //Post-Get
```

Tengo 2 middlewares unlogged y logged

Aqui estan mis rutas:

```
router.use(logged.unlogged);
router.use("/logout",logged.logged);
router.route("/login").get(login.login_get).post(login.login_post);
router.route("/recuperar").get(recuperar.recuperar_get).post(recuperar.recuperar_post);
router.route("/registrar").get(registrar.registrar_get).post(registrar.registrar_post);
router.route("/logout").get(logout);
```

Quiero que me dea acceso a esos endpoints cuando no esta logeado , y cuando esta logeado no me permita el acceso a los mismos, por eso pongo esos 2 middlewares.

Estos son mis middlewares

```
var logged=function(req,res,next){
    if(req.session.user_id!=undefined){
        next();
    }
    else{
        console.log(req.session);
        res.redirect("/");
    }
}

var unlogged=function(req,res,next){
    if(req.session.user_id!=undefined) res.redirect("/user/login");
    else{
        next();
    }
}


module.exports={
    logged:logged,
    unlogged:unlogged
}
```

Una ves que entro a login y pongo mis password y contraseña, encuentra al usuario y deberia redirigirme al endpoint /password el cual solo seactiva si esta logeado la persona.

```
User.findOne({userName:req.body.userName,password:req.body.password},function(err,us){
    if(err)console.log(String(err));
    console.log("Usuario encontra\n",us._id);
    if(us){
        req.session.user_id=us._id;
        console.log("Se redirigira a password");
        res.redirect("/password");
    }

    res.redirect("/");

});
```

Pero me sale el siguiente error

**Can't set headers after ther are sent**, pero no lo entiendo bien , dice que no puedo cambiar los headers luego de que los envie ,no veo mi error.

Ahora , no sé si la forma en la que estoy haciendo lo que quiero es la correcta , u hay otra forma más ligera para hacer lo que quiero.

De stackoverflow en ingles ,lo que entendi es posiblemente el error estea en el middleware ya que res.redirect modifica las cabeceras ,pero no me queda del todo claro.

**EDICION** 
El error se me quito poniendole un return a todos los redirect involucrados , pero no me queda claro porque es necesario el return , además deberia ponerle en todos,otra cuestión es si hay una manera mas fácil de ejecutar lo que trato de hacer.

Comment: "Can't set headers after ther are sent" se lanza cuando en alguna parte se intenta establecer una cabecera a la respuesta **después** que la respuesta ya ha sido transmitida. Al usar `return` forzas a que se detenga la ejecución del middleware y no siga paralelamente a los mapeos de las rutas.

Comment: Mitsu ahora tengo otra cuestión , con respecto a los middlewares como ves tengo 2 uno para ver si esta logeado y otro que hace lo contrario ,
en router.use pongo los 2 , pero como hago para poder darle mas importancia a la segunda en el caso de logout , pues cuando ejecuto todo , y envio un post a logout estando logeado , simplemente no me termina la session pues solo lee el primer middleware , estaba pensando ponerle un req.path.indexOf("logout"); pero si hay otra manera sería mejor,además si la manera de terminar la sessión en memoria seria poniendole un req.session.user_id=undefined?

Comment: @MitsuGami, deberías poner tu comentario como respuesta para que sea aceptada y evitar que el OP cambie la pregunta con su nueva duda. De otro modo, esta pregunta debería ser cerrada porque solo era un error de sintaxis o escritura.

Comment: @toledano, el OP ya encontró por sí mismo el error. Ante una nueva duda, deberá crear **una nueva** pregunta.

Comment: De acuerdo, @MitsuGami, a votar porque se cierre. Los problemas que son errores de sintaxis, tienen una temporalidad muy limitada y su solución solo ayuda a una persona, por lo que es mejor cerrarlas, [http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/473/](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/473/)

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta porque es un error tipográfico y fue resuelta de forma que no ayuda a futuros lectores.

Comment: Pues voto en contra , no creo que ha sido un error tipográfico , pues en la documentación de express no dice nada acerca de esto.

Comment: @KevinAB tu comentario a Mitsu califica como una nueva pregunta. Te recomiendo que la publiques respectivamente.

Answer (score 0):

El primer error esta en el primer middleware `router.use(logged.unlogged);` puesto que esto quiere decir que una vez el usuario se autentifique no va a poder acceder a ningun endpoint puesto que va a ser redirigido a `/user/login` tal como especifica este middleware. Para los endpoints que es necesario que el usuario no se haya logueado antes lo mejor es incluir este middleware en esa ruta especifica y no de forma general.

De hecho los middlewares correctos serian:

```
var logged=function(req,res,next){
    if(req.session.user_id!=undefined){
        next();
    }
    else{
        console.log(req.session);
        res.redirect("/user/login");
    }
}

var unlogged=function(req,res,next){
    if(req.session.user_id!=undefined) res.redirect("/");
    else{
        next();
    }
}
```

Comment: El tema está cerrado. Si ves los comentarios, verás que el tema se solucionó y su otra duda fue movida a otro tema. Por favor, revisa bien los temas antes de publicar. Saludos.

Comment: El tema puede estar cerrado pero el OP tenia un error bastante evidente en el codigo y nadie en los comentarios se lo ha señalado. Saludos

Comment: Si vuelves a ver un tema **en espera** no intentes responder. Haz click en **reabrir** para hacerlo y cuando se reabra, responder. Generalmente los temas en espera o cerrados, es por mala calidad de la pregunta o si el OP ya encontró la solución por su cuenta. Saludos.